# translate a boost ASIO buffer data to an opencv matrix of JPEG format

Tags: c++, opencv, sockets, boost-asio

I've built a C++ program to send a single jpg frame (along with a metadata header beforehand) over a TCP socket.. my trouble is.. I am getting the bytes successfully.. parsing my header and seeing my dimenions.. the number of bytes... but my question is.. how do I take this data now.. and recreate my JPEG?

I keep trying to cast the buffer but getting stopped out

```
std::cout << "[IMAGE_WIDTH]  = " << std::to_string(IMAGE_WIDTH) << std::endl;
std::cout << "[IMAGE_HEIGHT] = " << std::to_string(IMAGE_HEIGHT) << std::endl;
std::cout << "image bytes  = " << std::to_string(header_data.image_size_bytes) << std::endl;

Mat img = Mat::zeros(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, CV_8UC3);
const unsigned char* image_data_matrix = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const unsigned char*>(second_receive_buffer.data());
img.data = image_data_matrix;
imshow("server", img);
waitKey(100);
```

error I get from `gcc`

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sockets-client.dir/src/client.cpp.o
/bootstrap-cpp-sockets/client/src/client.cpp:81:28: error: assigning to 'uchar *' (aka 'unsigned char *') from 'const unsigned char *' discards qualifiers
                img.data = image_data_matrix;
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/sockets-client.dir/src/client.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/sockets-client.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**Full Client.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    try{
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        tcp::endpoint end_point(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 3200);
        tcp::socket socket(io_service);
        socket.connect(end_point);
        boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
        boost::asio::streambuf receive_buffer;

        // Now we retrieve the message header of 64 bytes
        size_t header_size = 64;
        boost::asio::read(socket, receive_buffer, boost::asio::transfer_exactly(header_size), ignored_error);

        if ( ignored_error && ignored_error != boost::asio::error::eof ) {
            cout << "first receive failed: " << ignored_error.message() << endl;
        } else {
            image_metadata_t header_data = parse_header(receive_buffer);

            const int IMAGE_WIDTH = header_data.width;
            const int IMAGE_HEIGHT = header_data.height;

            // Now we retrieve the frame itself
            boost::asio::streambuf second_receive_buffer;
            boost::asio::read(socket, second_receive_buffer, boost::asio::transfer_exactly(header_data.image_size_bytes), ignored_error);
            if( ignored_error && ignored_error != boost::asio::error::eof ) {
                cout << "SECOND receive failed: " << ignored_error.message() << endl;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "[IMAGE_WIDTH]  = " << std::to_string(IMAGE_WIDTH) << std::endl;
                std::cout << "[IMAGE_HEIGHT] = " << std::to_string(IMAGE_HEIGHT) << std::endl;
                std::cout << "image bytes  = " << std::to_string(header_data.image_size_bytes) << std::endl;

                Mat img = Mat::zeros(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, CV_8UC3);
                const unsigned char* image_data_matrix = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const unsigned char*>(second_receive_buffer.data());
                img.data = image_data_matrix;
                imshow("server", img);
                waitKey(100);
            }
        }
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

the eventual finished program will keep reading the socket, receiving a header with the metadata.. and showing the next frame.. hopefully 30 Frames per second will be hit but.. first thing first I just want to prove i can do this with one frame.. and build up from there.

Thanks !

Comment: `img.data = image_data_matrix;` -- don't do that. If you need to create a `Mat` that reuses an external pixel buffer, use the [appropriate constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a). At best, you're wasting memory and time by allocating and zero initializing a buffer that you don't use. Additionally, you're making the internal state inconsistent, since you don't modify things like `datastart`, `dataend`, etc...

Comment: Also, if it's a JPEG on client side, and you want a JPEG on server side, why not just send the file data as is? It's gonna be a lot less data, since JPEG is compressed, an you'll avoid degrading the quality due to another round of lossy compression. | Although near the end of the text you claim you want to show it, in which case the "recreate my JPEG" you mention earlier seems irrelevant and misleading.

Comment: Instead of `streambuf` use a `vector` wrapped by `boost::asio::buffer`. Or even better, since at that point you already know the shape of the `Mat`, then allocate it before reading and wrap `img.data` using `boost::asio::buffer`, and read directly into the `Mat`.

Comment: @DanMašek it is not a file on the other side per se.. I use OpenCV to encode it in a JPEG but.. there never was a file.  I took a screen capture using the OS's library.. https://github.com/smasherprog/screen_capture_lite

Comment: also you say instead of streambuf.. but it's not up to me how to use boost ASIO library .. and this example is basically bog standard when utilizing streams... are you suggesting I modify the buffer into a vector?

Comment: switching constructors was tried already .. here's the error

`client.cpp:85:27: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'cv::Mat'
                Mat img = cv::Mat(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, CV_8UC3, boost::asio::buffer_cast<const void*>(second_receive_buffer.data()));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239197/discussion-between-erik-and-dan-masek).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some clarification on my part with @Dan in the chat.. I modified both the server side and client side.. I append them both here now for anyone else trying to send JPG data over the wire

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp> 
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
 
// source https://www.programmerall.com/article/7721373696/
// source https://cppsecrets.com/users/14041151035752494957504952535764103109971051084699111109/Programming-in-C00-using-boostasio.php
bool flag = false;    

void servershow()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            //imshow("server",img);
            waitKey(1);
        }   
    }
}

cv::Mat retrieve_data(){

    std::string image_path = "/YOUR_IMAGE.jpg";
    cv::Mat image;
    image = imread(image_path, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    if(! image.data ) {
        std::cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
    }
    return image;
}


int main()
{
    boost::thread thrd(&servershow);
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 3200));
        
        for (;;) {
            tcp::socket socket(io_service);
            acceptor.accept(socket);
            boost::system::error_code ignored_error;

            //retrieve the frame to be sent
            cv::Mat frame = retrieve_data();
            std::vector<std::uint8_t> buff;
            cv::imencode(".jpg", frame, buff, param);

            // now we send the header message
            std:: string image_dimensions = "6016Wx3384H";
            std:: string image_buff_bytes = std::to_string(buff.size());
            std::string message_header = image_dimensions + "," +  image_buff_bytes;
            std::cout << "sending measage header of " << std::to_string(message_header.length()) << " bytes...." << std::endl;
            message_header.append(63 - message_header.length(), ' ');
            message_header = message_header + '\0';

            socket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(message_header), ignored_error);

            socket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(buff), ignored_error);

            flag = true;
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    thrd.join();

    return 0; 
}
```

Client retrieval

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

// source https://www.programmerall.com/article/7721373696/
// source https://cppsecrets.com/users/14041151035752494957504952535764103109971051084699111109/Programming-in-C00-using-boostasio.php

struct image_metadata_t {
    int width;
    int height;
    size_t image_size_bytes;
};

image_metadata_t parse_header(boost::asio::streambuf &buffer){

    std::string data_buff_str = std::string(boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(buffer.data()));
    cout << data_buff_str << endl;

    int width_pos = data_buff_str.find("W"); 
    int x_pos = data_buff_str.find("x"); 
    int height_pos = data_buff_str.find("H"); 
    int comma_pos = data_buff_str.find(","); 

    std::cout << "data_buff_str.substr(x_pos+1,height_pos) " << data_buff_str.substr(x_pos+1,height_pos) <<std::endl;

    image_metadata_t meta_data;
    meta_data.width = std::stoi(data_buff_str.substr(0,width_pos));
    meta_data.height = std::stoi(data_buff_str.substr(x_pos+1,height_pos));
    meta_data.image_size_bytes = std::stoi(data_buff_str.substr(data_buff_str.find(",") + 1));

    return meta_data;
}


cv::Mat GetImageFromMemory(uchar* image, int length, int flag) {
    std::vector<uchar> data = std::vector<uchar>(image, image + length);
    cv::Mat ImMat = imdecode(data, flag);

    return ImMat;
}

int main()
{
    try{
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        tcp::endpoint end_point(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 3200);
        tcp::socket socket(io_service);
        socket.connect(end_point);
        boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
        boost::asio::streambuf receive_buffer;

        // Now we retrieve the message header of 64 bytes
        size_t header_size = 64;
        boost::asio::read(socket, receive_buffer, boost::asio::transfer_exactly(header_size), ignored_error);

        if ( ignored_error && ignored_error != boost::asio::error::eof ) {
            cout << "first receive failed: " << ignored_error.message() << endl;
        } else {
            image_metadata_t header_data = parse_header(receive_buffer);

            const int IMAGE_WIDTH = header_data.width;
            const int IMAGE_HEIGHT = header_data.height;

            // Now we retrieve the frame itself
            std::cout << "Now asing for image bytes of size " << std::to_string(header_data.image_size_bytes) << std::endl;
            //boost::asio::streambuf second_receive_buffer;
            std::vector<std::uint8_t> buff(header_data.image_size_bytes);
            boost::asio::read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(buff), boost::asio::transfer_exactly(header_data.image_size_bytes), ignored_error);
            if( ignored_error && ignored_error != boost::asio::error::eof ) {
                cout << "SECOND receive failed: " << ignored_error.message() << endl;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "[IMAGE_WIDTH]  = " << std::to_string(IMAGE_WIDTH) << std::endl;
                std::cout << "[IMAGE_HEIGHT] = " << std::to_string(IMAGE_HEIGHT) << std::endl;
                std::cout << "image bytes  = " << std::to_string(header_data.image_size_bytes) << std::endl;

                cv::Mat img(cv::imdecode(buff, cv::IMREAD_ANYCOLOR));

                imshow("client", img);
                waitKey(5000);
            }
        }
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```